# trash output when run a std:: vector<double> code in linux terminal - C++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, stdvector

I am trying to make a simple std::vector code on C++ with g++ on linux terminal but confused with the output on the terminal itself.

My code is simple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()  {
  double xl;
  int nx=5;
  double delta_x;
  int i=0;
  std::vector<double> x(nx);

  for(i=0; i <=nx; i++)  {
    x[i]=0.0005;
    std::cout<<x[i]<<std::endl;
  }
return 0;
}
```

when I compile:

```
$ g++ grid2.cpp -o grid2
```

It succeeded and gives a grid2 executable. The problem arise when I run the executable:

```
$ ./grid2
```

gives me output like this on the terminal:

```
./grid2[0x400929]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 13372783                           /mnt/home/FINALS/codeDNS_AKA_MY_MAIN_DIR/basic_CPP/grid2
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 13372783                           /mnt/home/FINALS/codeDNS_AKA_MY_MAIN_DIR/basic_CPP/grid2
01f23000-01f55000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f13fc000000-7f13fc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13fc021000-7f1400000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1403971000-7f1403b0c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 790319                     /usr/lib/libc-2.22.so
7f1403b0c000-7f1403d0b000 ---p 0019b000 08:06 790319                     /usr/lib/libc-2.22.so
7f1403d0b000-7f1403d0f000 r--p 0019a000 08:06 790319                     /usr/lib/libc-2.22.so
7f1403d0f000-7f1403d11000 rw-p 0019e000 08:06 790319                     /usr/lib/libc-2.22.so
7f1403d11000-7f1403d15000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1403d15000-7f1403d2b000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 790384                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7f1403d2b000-7f1403f2a000 ---p 00016000 08:06 790384                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7f1403f2a000-7f1403f2b000 rw-p 00015000 08:06 790384                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7f1403f2b000-7f1404028000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 790449                     /usr/lib/libm-2.22.so
7f1404028000-7f1404227000 ---p 000fd000 08:06 790449                     /usr/lib/libm-2.22.so
7f1404227000-7f1404228000 r--p 000fc000 08:06 790449                     /usr/lib/libm-2.22.so
7f1404228000-7f1404229000 rw-p 000fd000 08:06 790449                     /usr/lib/libm-2.22.so
7f1404229000-7f140439b000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 790552                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f140439b000-7f140459b000 ---p 00172000 08:06 790552                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f140459b000-7f14045a5000 r--p 00172000 08:06 790552                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f14045a5000-7f14045a7000 rw-p 0017c000 08:06 790552                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f14045a7000-7f14045ab000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f14045ab000-7f14045cd000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 790282                     /usr/lib/ld-2.22.so
7f1404791000-7f1404797000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f14047ca000-7f14047cc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f14047cc000-7f14047cd000 r--p 00021000 08:06 790282                     /usr/lib/ld-2.22.so
7f14047cd000-7f14047ce000 rw-p 00022000 08:06 790282                     /usr/lib/ld-2.22.so
7f14047ce000-7f14047cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffec8a9b000-7ffec8abc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffec8bef000-7ffec8bf1000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffec8bf1000-7ffec8bf3000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

But the (another) weird thing is, when I change the

```
std::vector<double>
```

into

```
std::vector<float>
```

Those trash are all gone. And I can see the clean output right on my terminal.

And the other thing, when I print the output to another file like this:

```
$ ./grid2 > test.txt
```

the results are the same for both double and float. No trash, clean output. It's like the trash only appear on my terminal.

I am novice on linux and c++, so please if anyone know what I'm facing, I'll be very happy to hear that :)

Comment: Side-note: If you want to initialise all elements in your vector to a value, just do it in the constructor: `std::vector<double> x( nx, 0.0005 );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted, you have undefined behavior.

Although changing the `<=` to `<` *does* work, it just makes this code correct. It doesn't "immunize" you against running into essentially the same problem again soon.

One alternative would be to use the "range-based" `for` loop like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()  {
  double xl;
  int nx=5;
  double delta_x;
  int i=0;
  std::vector<double> x(nx);

  for(double &d : x)  {
    d=0.0005;
    std::cout<<d<<"\n";
  }
}
```

Though in this case, you're filling it with all identical values, so it's probably better to just initialize it that way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()  {
    std::vector<double> x(5, 0.0005);

    for (double const &d : x)
        std::cout << d << "\n";
}
```

The range-based `for` loop makes it much more difficult to accidentally attempt to access outside the bounds of the collection.

As an aside: note the use of `"\n"` instead of `std::endl`. I would recommend against using `std::endl` in general--on the rare occasion that you need what it does, make that explicit with `std::cout << "\n" << std::flush;`. In the much more common case that you didn't really want that `flush`, just omit it. `endl` does both, even though the `flush` is almost never desired (and most people aren't aware it even happens).

Answer (score 3):

`x` has 5 elements. Unfortunately you are accessing 6 - your `for` loop gives `i` values from 0 to 5 inclusive, which is a total of 6. Accessing `x[5]` is undefined behaviour; if you're lucky it crashes in an obvious way, but anything could happen.

You either need to make `x` bigger, or write your loop as

```
for(i=0; i < nx; i++)
```

(using `<` rather than `<=`).

Comment: Weirdly, it does in fact work with a vector of `float`. Spooky undefined behavior.

Comment: "Appears to work." Undefine behaviour allows the program to do anything - including what you expect. Don't rely on that.

Comment: @Nooble Distinguish "seems work" and "does in fact work".

Comment: @Nooble If you insist to explain why it seems work: `float` and `double` are different in size. The memory allocation may be therefore different.